# Debug transient 404 errors

Tags: django, tastypie

I sometimes get http 404 errors in my client on a certain url on my `tastypie` API.

However, when I access it manually via my browswer, it works all the time with the exact URL that the client is requesting.

This is a GET call with some query parameters:
https://example.com/v2/xxx?limit=&offset=&timestamp=

How can I debug this?

**UPDATE 1**

It looks like the error is returned by `tastypie` because the response body is {"error_message": "Sorry, this request could not be processed. Please try again later."}

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that it is a `NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTIONS` in tastypie `resources.py`, but how can I debug a transient problem? The data is pretty static and does not change.

Comment: Try using the Chrome dev tools to generate a curl command which exactly replicates the failing request. The problem may still be transient but at least you'll be certain you're using identical headers/user-agent/params/etc when testing

Comment: I have turned on send_broken_email. In `resources.py` _handle_500 method, it will send an email with the exception traceback.

Comment: Interesting, my stuff has always been behind firewalls with no email access to am unsure how helpful that will be. In the meantime, to track things down... Can you post your relevant lines from, `urls.py` / `views.py` so we can see the execution path being taken?

Comment: can you post a full stacktrace?  The key is probably in the stack trace.  If you have absolutely no clue, you want to put in your own exception handler and log as much info as you can.  Likely candidates are headers and cookies/session data, so make sure you log those.  If you have caching on, that may be related too.